# Is this a C-17 (and why is it here)?

Tags: aircraft-identification

This aircraft flew overhead at less than 1000 ft a little while ago. We think it's a C-17. We can't figure out what it was doing...

[image]
(Click [here for full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6kjL.jpg))

We're in Culver City, between LAX and Santa Monica. It was traveling south to north, about 4:50 this afternoon.

Scared the neighborhood...

Comment: Why were you scared?

Comment: That is way more than 1000 feet.

Comment: the whole neigborhood, huh?

Comment: They aren't quiet aircraft.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that is indeed a C-17. As to why it's in the area, only the Air Force would know.
[image]

https://www.boeing.com/defense/c-17-globemaster-iii/#/overview

Comment: The images don’t do justice to its altitude. Nor the fact that it was banking right then left .. Exciting..

Comment: @DavidDelMonte It’s not a big deal, dude. Edwards AFB isn’t far by flight and there are plenty of military installations in the area that it could be practicing with. It could be anything: Touch and go’s, dropping paratroopers, doing search and rescue training.... Or, you know, chemtrails...

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen them first hand, so that's why I was confident enough to say that it is indeed a C-17.